# Android Jsoup change font-family in style tag

Tags: android, jsoup

I need to change font-family to a custom one after loading html into WebView. Basically I need to get this:

```
 <style>
            @font-face {
            font-family: 'MyFont';
            src: url('file:///android_asset/Custom-Font.otf')
            }
            body { font-family: 'MyFont', serif; font-size: 17px; color: #000; }
            a { color: #000; }
 </style>
```

from

```
<style>
            body { font-family: 'Helvetica', serif; font-size: 17px; color: #000; }
            a { color: #000; }
</style>
```

Html is dynamically loaded, not from assets. I use Jsoup, but cannot get this font-family parameter so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSoup does not parse the CSS for you.  It ends up in a `DataNode` hanging off the `style` element.  From there, you are on your own in terms of parsing.  If you have a simple search and replace, you can use a regular expression to do the work.  For complicated situations, you  can look at a [CSS Parser][1].  Your situation looks relatively simple, but given just one exemplar it is hard to tell which elements you want preserved.   Here is a sketch of the basic idea, you may need to modify to fully fit your situation.  The basic idea is to get the `DataNode` from the `Style` tag and using a regex to search and replace the field.

```
final String newFontInfo = "@font-face { \n"
        + "font-family: 'MyFont';\n"
        + "src: url('file:///android_asset/Custom-Font.otf')\n" + "}\n";
Elements styles = doc.select("style");
for (Element style : styles) {
    for (DataNode data : style.dataNodes()) {
        String dataTxt = data.getWholeData();
        if (dataTxt.contains("font-family")) {
             final String newData = dataTxt.replaceAll("font-family:\\s*'[^']*'","font-family: 'MyFont'");
             data.setWholeData(newFontInfo + newData);
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Many thanks, would you be so kind to tell how to change regex string to match "word word"?

Comment: I do not understand what you want, if you want to match the literal string "word word", or any known string, you do not need a regex.  If you are looking for something else, you will have to clarify.  Learning to compose regex's is extremely useful for a number of situations.  Have a look at the `Pattern` [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), or search the web for a regex tutorial, so you can have it in your toolbox.